# Is there an integrated way of benchmarking a Parallel.For loop by iterations per time interval?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.for

I have a `Parallel.For` statement that is used to search for certain values.  When a value is found, it exports it to a file.  Finding such values are rare, so once I receive enough results in the file, I stop the execution of the code by killing the application.

What I would like to do is integrate into my `For` loop statement some form of monitor that can tell me how many searches have been executed a second.

I'd assume this is a very basic, necessary metric.  Is there a way to benchmark Parallel.For, in this manner?

FYI, this is a console application and the console also outputs found results.  I'm hoping write to the display a close-to-accurate "Searches/sec" metric. Can I do this?  These numbers don't need to be perfect, but I'm but they should be accurate within 5-10%.

**EDIT**

Ok, so everyone always ask for a code sample, even when there isn't a need for one.  But that's not a problem.  I'll create a simple app below that will suffice in getting my point across.

Let's say I have the following program:

```
long minValue = 10000000;
string seed = "seed text";
object lockObj = new Object();

Parallel.For(1, Int32.Max, (i, ls) =>
{
  long val = DoCalcs(seed + i.ToString); //Assume that DoCalcs does some form of calculation.
  if (val < minValue)
  {
    lock (lockObj)
    {
      /* Write the value to a text file */
      Console.WriteLine("Found a smaller value ({0})!", minValue);
    }
  }
});
```

Ok, this application is simple enough.  Even though it can't run "forever", effectively it can because it's not going to run for an `Int32.Max` iterations.

How can I monitor and output how many times that this loop has executed in parallel, with a *reasonable* amount of accuracy.  I could add a global accumulator but my hunch is that using such a method would degrade performance.

Is there a tool within the Task Parallel Library that can report how many loop executions have taken place since the beginning of the call to `Parallel.For`, or is there a way to periodically query all executing tasks and safely retrieve how many iterations they've executed?

Comment: Please show us your current code

Comment: Well, I'll show a sample program-- one that can be benchmarked just as easily as mine.

Comment: Why would a global accumulator degrade performance in your opinion?

Comment: In my case, I'm trying to squeeze as much performance out of the system as possible.  If locking a single accumulator causes more overhead than some integrated solution that might be built into TPL, then I don't want to do that.  But, if that's the only option I have, or the overhead is quite insignificant, I don't mind using that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm posting my own answer to this question because I know this is an approach.  However, ***I'm not sure if there is a more-optimal means of doing this***.  If you have a better answer than this approach, then please post it or post comments on how to improve this approach.

**Potential Solution**

```
long minValue = 10000000;
string seed = "seed text";
object lockObj = new Object();

//Solution variables
int iter = 0;
object benchObj = new Object();
DateTime lastBenchmark = DateTime.Now;

Parallel.For(1, Int32.Max, (i, ls) =>
{
  long val = DoCalcs(seed + i.ToString); //Assume that DoCalcs does some form of calculation.
  if (val < minValue)
  {
    lock (lockObj)
    {
      /* Write the value to a text file */
      Console.WriteLine("Found a smaller value ({0})!", minValue);
    }
  }

  //My version of benchmark output
  lock(benchObj)
  {
    iter++;
    if (lastBenchmark.AddSeconds(5) < DateTime.Now)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("Executing {0:F3} kCalcs/s!", ((float)iter) / 5 / 1000);
       iter = 0;
       lastBenchmark = DateTime.Now;
    }        
  }
});
```

Is this as good as benchmarking `Parallel.For` can get or am I doing something wrong?